# Number of records in Apache Kafka topic has issue

Tags: apache-kafka

Could you please help me to address the query...

Recently we have posted lot of records for one message/event in a kafka topic . However the records are getting truncated and we are not able to see the full records in the topic once the producer posted into the topic . we are not able to figure out what are the settings has to fine tune to accept larger records for a single event/message in a topic .
Can someone guide me where to check these settings and do we need to change at Kafka Broker level or Producer level . we have fine tune below settings but no use ...
Could you please help why the records are getting truncated in event ormessage of topic ...

Comment: all set to 2 GB

Producer side
max.request.size
socket.buffer.size
send.buffer.bytes 

Broker side 
socket.request.max.bytes 
replica.fetch.max.bytes 
message.max.bytes 
max.messages.bytes

Comment: there are two possibilties - your kafka producer was not able to send the record or the broker lost the record after receiving it. Share the producer code so it can be verified.